# How to check if clipboard is equal to a predetermined number, or several numbers in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

```
; Copy cell 
var := clipboard
sleep, 1000
WinActivate, doesntmatter - Internet Explorer


IfEqual 30684047, %var%
{
    sleep, 500
    Send, inform
}
else 
{
    msgbox, nope
}
    return
```

My problem is that even though I have the correct number (30684047) in the clipboard, the code still goes straight to the MsgBox and tells me that the clipboard (%var%) isnt equal to the predetermined code.

What am i missing? I am 100% sure that %var% contains my copied code from the clipboard because if i do a MsgBox with %var% after i copy it, it gives me a box containing that correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look back at the documentation for IfEqual...you switched var and value.

```
; Copy cell 
var := clipboard
sleep, 1000
WinActivate, doesntmatter - Internet Explorer

IfEqual, var, 30684047
{
    sleep, 500
    Send, inform
}
else 
{
    msgbox, nope
}
    return
```

There's really no need to save off the value of clipboard to a different variable unless you're wanting to re-use that value after clipboard has later changed. So the above could also be:

```
WinActivate, doesntmatter - Internet Explorer
If (clipboard = "30684047") {
    sleep, 500
    SendInput, inform
}
else
    msgbox, nope
return
```

Comment: @Simo Todorov: `IfEqual` is deprecated. You're advised to use the `If` form as in the second piece of code above.